# Instant Run - difference between hot, warm and cold swap

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I have updated latest to version of android studio (2.1). It was mentioned in documentation that android studio latest version will support hot warm and cold Swapping in instant run feature of android studio .

Can any one tell me what is the difference between hot warm and cold Swapping

Comment: this may be useful: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html

Answer (score 7):

- **Hot Swapping :–**

  Hot swapping occurs when the code within an existing
  method implementation is changed. The new method implementation is
  used next time it is called by the app. A hot swap occurs
  instantaneously and, if configured, is accompanied by a toast message
  on the device screen that reads “Applied code changes without
  activity restart”.
- **Warm Swapping :–**

  When a change is made to a resource file of the
  project (for example a layout change or the modification of a string
  or color resource setting) an Instant Run warm swap is performed. A
  warm swap involves the restarting of the currently running activity.
  Typically the screen will flicker as the activity restarts. A warm
  swap is reported on the device screen by a toast message that reads
  “Applied changes, restarted activity”.
- **Cold Swapping :–**

  Structural code changes such as the addition of a new
  method, a change to the signature of an existing method or a change
  to the class hierarchy of the project triggers a cold swap in which
  the entire app is restarted. Note that a cold swap does not result in
  the app being re-installed on the device.
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Read the [Official Documentation for Instant Run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) to get full detail. Major details are as follows:

> ### What are hot swap, warm swap and cold swap?

**Hot Swap**

> This is the fastest type of swap and makes changes visible almost
> instantly. Your application keeps running and a stub method with the
> new implementation is used the next time the method is called.

**Warm Swap**

> This swap is still very fast, but requires an automatic activity
> restart when Instant Run pushes the changed resources to the target
> device. Your app keeps running, but a small flicker may appear on the
> screen as the activity restarts—this is normal.

**Cold Swap**

> (API level 21 or higher): Instant Run pushes the structural code
> changes to the target device and restarts the whole app.
>
> For target devices running API level 20 or lower, Android Studio
> deploys a full build of the APK.

---

> ### **Type of code changes that trigger each of these swaps**

**What Triggres Hot Swap?**

```
Change implementation code of an existing instance method or static method
```

**What Triggers Warm Swap?**

```
Change or remove an existing resource
```

**What Triggers Cold Swap?**

```
Structural code changes, such as:

 - Add, remove, or change:
 - an annotation
 - an instance field
 - a static field
 - a static method signature
 - an instance method signature

Change which parent class the current class inherits from

Change the list of implemented interfaces

Change a class static initializer

Reorder layout elements that utilize dynamic resource IDs
```

Comment: Why can't I trigger the `Hot swap` ?  Does it only happens on the simulator?  And when it happens, do I need to restart the activity?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called Insant Run.

Detailed description how and when it works is listed in table in [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run).

Answer (score 0):

I found this perfect post. It explains the concept with Graphical Illustrations.

https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f#.g7r0yk9g4

The quick review is:

**Hot Swap:-** Changes made in Running Code. No restart Required. Saves time.

**Warm Swap:-** Changes are made and the particular activity is restarted.

**Cold Swap:-** The activity is restarted to access the changes.

P.S.:- From Personal Experiences, In Hot Swap, the values assigned in onCreate() are not available onResume() [or outside onCreate], thus getting null. Hence, if values are initialized only in onCreate() block, onResume() may throw a nullPointerException.
(I am not sure if this is the only case so,Please Comment/Edit if my logic and reasoning is wrong.)